# ffmpeg stream video file from ubuntu to youtube

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, youtube, stream

I'm trying to create a stream to youtube. I could see how preview button changes into enable state. However it never actually changes from offline.
And it gives me several error. What am I doing wrong?

```
     ffmpeg -i video.flv -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/XXXXXX


  ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers

      built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
      configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
      libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
      libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
      libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
      libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
      libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
      libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
      libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
      libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
      libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
    Input #0, flv, from 'video.flv':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt  
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: qt  
        com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2017-07-20T21:44:12+0700
        com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
        com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 6s Plus
        com.apple.quicktime.software: 10.3.2
        encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
      Duration: 00:01:15.24, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4454 kb/s
        Stream #0:0: Video: flv1, yuv420p, 1920x1080, 200 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
        Stream #0:1: Audio: adpcm_swf, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 176 kb/s
    Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/XXXXXX':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : qt  
        minor_version   : 0
        compatible_brands: qt  
        com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2017-07-20T21:44:12+0700
        com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
        com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 6s Plus
        com.apple.quicktime.software: 10.3.2
        encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
        Stream #0:0: Video: flv1 (flv) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 1k tbn, 29.97 tbc
        Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 flv
        Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 44100 Hz, mono, s16p
        Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libmp3lame
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (flv1 (flv) -> flv1 (flv))
      Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (adpcm_swf (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    [flv @ 0x162bac0] Failed to update header with correct duration.ate=4125.4kbits/s    
    [flv @ 0x162bac0] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
    frame= 2255 fps=114 q=31.0 Lsize=   37863kB time=00:01:15.24 bitrate=4122.0kbits/s    
    video:37194kB audio:588kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global
```

headers:0kB mixing overhead: 0.213941%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When streaming a video file you should use the `-re` option. Otherwise `ffmpeg` will attempt to encode it as fast as it can.

You can try to stream copy, assuming your file formats and parameters are suitable to do so:

```
ffmpeg -re -i video.flv -c copy -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/XXXXXX
```

Or re-encode:

```
ffmpeg -re -i video.flv -c:v libx264 -b:v 4000k -maxrate 4000k -bufsize 6000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 60 -c:a aac -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/XXXXXX
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I figured out - my issue connected with youtube quality settings and with a video duration.